# how to prove this equation with summation and logarithm?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Say I have equation below, how can I prove it?

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k} k =\log\left( \frac 1 {1-z} \right), \text{ if }|z|<1$$

Don't really know how to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $0\leq t\leq z<1$, $$\int_{0}^{z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^kdt=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{z} t^kdt=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}$$

Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k=\frac{1}{1-t}$$

and $$\int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{1-t}=-\log (1-z)=\log \frac{1}{1-z}$$

Similar for $-1<z\leq 0$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what to do then.

Comment: @hcnak can you do now?

Comment: Hi,I don't know why $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k=\frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: Thank you,I know how it works now

Comment: @hcnak you have accepted my answer 3 times and un-accepted 2 time! (I don't know why) Please, if you have any doubt write a comment here.

Comment: Sorry foe that , after multiple time comuinicate with my classmate,I know now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$ for $|z|<1$. You can show that $f'(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$. Then integrate.

Comment: why $f'(z)$ isn't $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k-1} $? I mean, since 
 ${a^k}'=ka^{k-1}$ . And I don't really know why $f'(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k-1} = \frac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: $f'(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{k-1} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k}$

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = 1/(1-z)$ because $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ is a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof
that doesn't assume convergence.

Start with
$\sum_{k=0}^m x^k
=\dfrac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x}
$
for
$0 \le x < 1$.

Therefore
$\dfrac1{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^m x^k+\dfrac{x^{m+1}}{1-x}
$.

Integrating from 
$0$ to $z$,
where
$0 \le z < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
-\ln(1-z)
&=\int_0^z \dfrac{dx}{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m \int_0^z x^k dx+\int_0^z\dfrac{x^{m+1}dx}{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m \dfrac{z^{k+1}}{k+1}+E_m(z)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \dfrac{z^{k}}{k}+E_m(z)\\
\end{array}
$

where
$E_m(z) \ge 0$
and
$E_m(z)
=\int_0^z\dfrac{x^{m+1}dx}{1-x}\\
\le\dfrac1{1-z}\int_0^zx^{m+1}dx\\
=\dfrac{z^{m+2}}{(m+2)(1-z)}\\
$.

Therefore
$0
\le -\ln(1-z)-\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \dfrac{z^{k}}{k}
\le \dfrac{z^{m+2}}{(m+2)(1-z)}
$.

Since
$\dfrac{z^{m+2}}{(m+2)(1-z)}
\to 0$
as $m \to \infty$
for
$0 \le z \lt 1$,
the series converges.